# How to protect a button with a password?

Tags: vba, button, passwords

I would like to know  how I can protect a button with a password before run the macro?

I tried the following code, which works good, but I couldn't exit in case of the password is incorrect for the third time.

```
strPassword = "HR"
For lTries = 1 To 3
    strPassTry = InputBox("Enter Password please", "RUN MACRO")
    If strPassTry = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bSuccess = strPassword = strPassTry
    If bSuccess = True Then Exit For
    MsgBox "Password incorrect"
Next lTries
```

Comment: The user can open the macro and read the password.

Answer (score 0):

@SLaks comment aside...

```
strPassword = "HR"

For lTries = 1 To 3
    strPassTry = InputBox("Enter Password please", "RUN MACRO")
    If strPassTry = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bSuccess = strPassword = strPassTry
    If bSuccess Then Exit For
    MsgBox "Password incorrect"
Next lTries

If Not bSuccess Then 
    Msgbox "Wrong password supplied!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)